# What exactly is the purpose of the resistors in this diagram?

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, analog, pins, piezo

I don't claim to know a huge amount about electronics, so I just want to understand the basic flow of electricity in this schematic better. I imagine the purpose of the 1M ohm resistors are to draw off any excess current to the ground so it doesn't overload the board. Is that right?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but when the piezo is stressed it allows electricity to flow from the board to ground. And the board is continually trying to output from those analog pins, right? But can the piezo really cause that much current to be drawn?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. That's not a schematic (which shows the schema of a circuit) but rather it's a wiring diagram (and they're disliked because they don't explain the schema). We have no idea from the diagram what the circuit is supposed to do, whether the piezo is an input or output (your text suggests input) and what they are connected to on the board. You might find someone who knows what it is.

Comment: *I imagine the purpose of the 1M ohm resistors are to draw off any excess current to the ground so it doesn't overload the board. Is that right?* Nope. Your explanation is complete and utter nonsense. Things simply do not work like that. Sorry.

Comment: *but when the piezo is stressed it allows electricity to flow from the board to ground* Nonsense as well. Ground is just a concept electrical engineers use as a reference point. Kind of like when you measure the size of a room, you start at some point. Electronics ground is like that, just a starting point. It has no real meaning for circuits that are not actually connected with a wire to a metal pin inserted in planet earth (and even then, it is still only a reference point).

Comment: Here is the [whole thread](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=85186.0) discussing this.

Comment: Let me stress that it is OK to build a project and experiment with it without understanding the electronic side of things. But if you do want to understand then be aware that you have to read into that and study it. Making assumptions will only lead to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

A piezoelectric transducer will produce a flow of current dependent on the physical stress it is exposed to. Within its useful range of voltages, the amount of current that flows is roughly constant. So, due to ohm's law, the voltage produced will depend on the resistance presented -- more resistance will mean the same current produces a higher voltage. The 1M value was chosen by experimentation to produce a voltage the Arduino will detect with a reasonable input to the sensors.

With no resistor at all, the piezo could produce a voltage with no input whatsoever. It would just act like a charged capacitor.

With too low a resistance, the transducer would not be able to produce enough current to get an input detected by the Arduino.

Answer (score -2):

What I've learned from [Eugene's link](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=85186.0):

1) Piezos generate electricity themselves and it flows out of the red wire, not the black.

2) The purpose of the resistor is to reduce the voltage entering the board to a readable level.

3) The purpose of wiring the resistor in parallel rather than in series is to give the current "somewhere else to go", which I take to mean also to reduce the current entering the board.

Comment: "*it flows out of the red wire, not the black*" That doesn't make any sense. Also, the resistor both increases and decreases the voltage.